# How does asynchronous training work in distributed Tensorflow?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tensorflow, neural-network, distributed

I've read [Distributed Tensorflow Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed), and it mentions that in asynchronous training,

> each replica of the graph has an independent training loop that executes without coordination.

From what I understand, if we use parameter-server with data parallelism architecture, it means each worker computes gradients and updates its own weights without caring about other workers updates for distributed training Neural Network. As all weights are shared on parameter server (ps), I think ps still has to coordinate (or aggregate) weight updates from all workers in some way. I wonder how does the aggregation work in asynchronous training. Or in more general words, how does asynchronous training work in distributed Tensorflow?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you train asynchronously in Distributed TensorFlow, a particular worker does the following:

1. The worker **reads** all of the shared model parameters in parallel from the PS task(s), and copies them to the worker task. These reads are uncoordinated with any concurrent writes, and no locks are acquired: in particular the worker may see partial updates from one or more other workers (e.g. a subset of the updates from another worker may have been applied, or a subset of the elements in a variable may have been updated).
2. The worker **computes** gradients locally, based on a batch of input data and the parameter values that it read in step 1.
3. The worker **sends** the gradients for each variable to the appropriate PS task, and **applies** the gradients to their respective variable, using an update rule that is determined by the optimization algorithm (e.g. SGD, SGD with Momentum, Adagrad, Adam, etc.). The update rules  typically use (approximately) *commutative* operations, so they may be applied independently on the updates from each worker, and the state of each variable will be a running aggregate of the sequence of updates received.

In asynchronous training, each update from the worker is applied concurrently, and the updates may be somewhat coordinated if the optional `use_locking=True` flag was set when the respective optimizer (e.g. [`tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer)) was initialized. Note however that the locking here only provides mutual exclusion for two concurrent updates, and (as noted above) reads do not acquire locks; the locking does not provide atomicity across the entire set of updates.

(By contrast, in synchronous training, a utility like `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` will ensure that all of the workers read the same, up-to-date values for each model parameter; and that all of the updates for a synchronous step are aggregated before they are applied to the underlying variables. To do this, the workers are synchronized by a barrier, which they enter after sending their gradient update, and leave after the aggregated update has been applied to all variables.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the great Answer!!! I still have 2 questions here - 1. For asynchronous training, since each worker computes and updates weights independently, the shared weights are not synchronized during training. I wonder if we have to write a separate method to synchronize or aggregate weights manually from all workers after training. 2. In terms of performance (speed and training accuracy), is there any tradeoff here? Thanks!

Comment: 1. The updates to each variable are applied directly to a single instance of that variable, which is stored on the PS task(s): essentially, each worker performs the update `v -= learning_rate * grad_of_loss_wrt_v` for SGD (or something fancier for other optimization algorithms) on each variable `v`. You don't need to do anything extra to synchronize or aggregate the weights, because there's only one shared copy!

Comment: 2. Asynchronous training typically achieves higher *throughput* (in terms of training data consumed per unit time) than synchronous training, because it never needs to block on another worker. However, whether this leads to a faster time to accuracy will depend on the model, and the performance of your network, because you will probably need to run a larger number of steps when doing asynchronous training to reach the same accuracy as a synchronous training process.

Comment: 2. (continued) Many people have observed ([paper 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00981), [paper 2](http://www.pdl.cmu.edu/PDL-FTP/CloudComputing/GeePS-cui-eurosys16.pdf)) that, with modern GPU clusters and a fast interconnect, it is possible to make synchronous training run acceptably fast, and hence better to use that (for some problems) than asynchronous training.

Comment: @mrry: Can you please more fully explain the statement in step 3: "and applies the gradients to their respective variable" ? What is the subject of that statement: the worker or the parameter server task? If it's the worker that applies the update rule, then is that also the case for synchronous training as well?

Comment: You say that the update rules are only approximately commutative. This means that the resulting model differs from a model that was trained in a non-parallel manner, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

In asynchronous training there is no synchronization of weights among the workers. The weights are stored on the parameter server. Each worker loads and changes the shared weights independently from each other. This way if one worker finished an iteration faster than the other workers, it proceeds with the next iteration without waiting. The workers only interact with the shared parameter server and don't interact with each other.

Overall it can (depending on the task) speedup the computation significantly. However the results are sometimes worse than the ones obtained with the slower synchronous updates.

Comment: Oh Really?? I did a validation test on asynchronous training, and looked all worker weights are still synced in some ways. What really confused me is how those weights are synced in async training. I couldn't find answers on TF doc and its code, but I'm pretty sure they're synced.

Comment: @RuofanKong They are not synced, they just read and send gradients to the same variables that are stored on the ps. They work independently but they all read and write to the same variables on the ps. Each worker will have a very similar weights since they read from the same parameters on the ps, however when one worker updates the weights on the ps the others will only see the change when they read the variables from the ps again.

Comment: it is more recommended to use a smaller learning rate when using asynchronous mode？

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example in the documentation you link to:

```
with tf.device("/job:ps/task:0"):
  weights_1 = tf.Variable(...)
  biases_1 = tf.Variable(...)

with tf.device("/job:ps/task:1"):
  weights_2 = tf.Variable(...)
  biases_2 = tf.Variable(...)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:7"):
  input, labels = ...
  layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, weights_1) + biases_1)
  logits = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights_2) + biases_2)
  # ...
  train_op = ...

with tf.Session("grpc://worker7.example.com:2222") as sess:
  for _ in range(10000):
    sess.run(train_op)
```

You can see that the training is distributed on three machines which all share a copy of identical weights, but as is mentioned just below the example:

> In the above example, the variables are created on two tasks in the ps job, and the compute-intensive part of the model is created in the worker job. TensorFlow will insert the appropriate data transfers between the jobs (from ps to worker for the forward pass, and from worker to ps for applying gradients).

In other words, one gpu is used to calculate the forward pass and then transmits the results to the other two machines, while each of the other machines calculate the back propagation for a part of the weights and then send the results to the other machines so they can all update their weights appropriately.

GPUs are used to speed up matrix multiplications and parallel mathematical operations which are very intensive for both forward pass and back propagation. So distributed training simply means that you distribute these operations on many GPUs, the model is still synced between the machines, but now the back propagation of different weights can be calculated in parallel and the forward pass on a different mini-batch can be calculated at the same time as backprop from the previous mini-batch is still being calculated. Distributed training does not mean that you have totally independent models and weights on each machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since async training still has to sync weights among workers, I wonder if there is any performance difference with synchronous training in terms of training speed. Or in other words, which way would be preferred?

Comment: For very small enough models, doing it in a single GPU is better , but once your model gets large enough, asynchonous is much faster because doing all the backprops is the speed bottleneck and syncing weights is relatively fast in comparison. Typically you expect a 2 to 3 time speedup for doing it on 4 GPUs instead of 1 GPU.