# Asynchronous gradient descent in tensorflow under concurrent access

Tags: asynchronous, tensorflow, gradient

I have been having trouble implementing an asynchronous gradient descent in a multithreaded environment.

To describe the skeleton of my code, for each thread,

```
loop
    synchronize with global param
    < do some work / accumulate gradients on mini-batch >
    apply gradient descent to the global network, specifically,
    = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
end
```

where each thread has its own optimizer.

Now the problem is that, in defining the optimizer with 'use_locking=False', it does Not work, evidenced by the rewards generated by my reinforcement learning agent.

However, when I set the 'use_locking=True', it works so the algorithm is correct; it's just that the local gradients are not applied properly to the global param.

So some possible reasons I thought of were the following:
   1. While one thread is updating the global param, when another thread accesses the global param, the former thread cancels all remaining updates. And that too many threads access this global param concurrently, threads do all hard work for nothing.
   2. Referring to, [How does asynchronous training work in distributed Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147435), reading asynchronously is certain fine in the top of the loop. However, it may be that as soon as the thread is done applying the gradient, it goes to synchronizing from the global param too quickly that it does not fetch the updates from other threads.

Can you, hopefully tensorflow developer, help me what is really happening with 'use_locking' for this specific loop instance?

I have been spending days on this simple example. Although setting use_locking = True does solve the issue, it is not asynchronous in nature and it is also very slow.

I appreciate your help.