# How does Asynchronous Distributed Tensorflow handle parameter updates from different Optimizers?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have read the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147435/how-does-asynchronous-training-work-in-distributed-tensorflow) but still do not understand how Asynchronous Distributed Tensorflow deals with updates from different optimizers?

This is how I think of it. Each worker will send its gradients to parameter servers. Then, each parameter server will update the parameter based on the `apply_gradients(...)` call of the optimizer. If this is the case, then a parameter server would do *n* `apply_gradients()` where each gradient was computed on a somewhat stale view of parameters.

When making these calls with the `AdamOptimizer(..)` or `AdagradOptimizer(..)`, which mutate internal state such as momentum each of these calls in practice would get different values for these variables.

Does Distributed Asynchronous Tensorflow do anything different from what I just described? More generally, how does Tensorflow deal with asynchronous updates from optimizers which are *not commutative*? I know that I could use `SyncReplicasOptimizer` to eliminate these inconsistencies.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent/issues/67#issuecomment-280782325) could shed a little light

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but that doesn't help much. Asynchronous training with distributed tensorflow seems to be the standard yet from scanning through both github issues and tensorflow documentation it is not clear what the internals of async TF are. Since most optimizers are not commutative, it seems that Asynchronous training with different optimizers will give different results.