# Distributed TensorFlow: at low-level, how the workers and the ps interact with each other during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I'm studying how distributed TensorFlow handle its distributed computation in order to replicate its architecture. I need to understand at the low-level the operations done by workers and the operations done by the PS, I can't just rely on the correctness of the python API. [Here my previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150587/distributed-tensorflow-async-between-graph-replication-which-are-the-exactly).

> A PS (parameter server) keeps in memory the weights (i.e. the
>   parameters) and receives gradients, running the update step I wrote in
>   the code above. It does this every time it receives gradients from a
>   worker.
>
> A worker, on the other hand, looks up what's the current value of
>   weights in the PS, makes a copy of it locally, runs a forward and a
>   backward pass of the network on a batch of data and gets new
>   gradients, which then sends back to the PS.

So it seem that the worker calculate the gradients and then send the gradients to the PS that apply them updating the weights. But if I look at the code that I found in the [Distributed TensorFlow Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) I see that inside the worker code there is a call to the method minimize()

```
if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):

      # Build model...
      loss = ...
      global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

      train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
          loss, global_step=global_step) # < - - - - - - - - - HERE
```

If we look at the source code of the method minimize inside the Python API we saw that it call compute_gradients() and apply_gradients().

```
def minimize(self, loss, global_step=None, var_list=None,
               gate_gradients=GATE_OP, aggregation_method=None,
               colocate_gradients_with_ops=False, name=None,
               grad_loss=None):

    grads_and_vars = self.compute_gradients(
        loss, var_list=var_list, gate_gradients=gate_gradients,
        aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
        colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops,
        grad_loss=grad_loss)

    vars_with_grad = [v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None]
    if not vars_with_grad:
      raise ValueError(
          "No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops"
          " that do not support gradients, between variables %s and loss %s." %
          ([str(v) for _, v in grads_and_vars], loss))

    return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step,
                                name=name)
```

It seem that the worker does the compute and the apply operations. What kind of information then the workers send to the PS ? They send maybe the weights already updated by the applying of the gradients ? And if the PS receive the all weights how do it merge them ?